# Improved edits by Community♦ bot

Tags: support, suggested-edits, community-user

I was going through Suggested Edits and noticed [Community♦](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community) had reviewed the edit suggestion.

The bot has done a number of edits.

> Community has approved 21419 edit suggestions and rejected 4859 edit suggestions and improved 242 edit suggestions

But how can the bot "improve" edits?

Comment: [How can Community♦ improve edit suggestions? · meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292326/371617)

Comment: I removed the [meta-tag:discussion] tag because I don't think you intended this to be a discussion how Community♦ should be allowed to improve edits (or something like that) – please add it again if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [How can Community♦ improve edit suggestions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292326/371617), on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com),  [S.L. Barth](https://askubuntu.com/users/254326/s-l-barth) says that:

> It looks like this happens when a reviewer chooses "Improve Edit", but the reviewing user is later deleted.

...

> These reviews still have to be credited to someone, and Community is the natural choice.

This would also be the same for Approve and Reject (plus Community♦'s extra automatic ones).